# cannot use ^xxx outside of match clauses

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

This function:

```
defp entries(query, page_number, page_size) do
  offset = page_size * (page_number - 1)

  query
  |> limit([_], ^page_size) # error
  |> offset([_], ^offset)
  |> Repo.all
end
```

gives an exception:

```
cannot use ^pg_size outside of match clauses
```

Why is that and how to fix it?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

This is most usually a sign that you haven't imported appropriate macros from `Ecto.Query`.

Comment: The ones that you attempt to use: limit and offset.

Comment: `import Ecto.Query`. I would strongly suggest going through http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html and https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html if you haven't already.

Comment: Is it possible to report root cause error for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
query
|> limit(page_size)
|> offset(offset)
|> Repo.all
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause for this error is misspelled words. In my case it was `form` instead of `from`.

Answer (score -1):

You must use ^ (pin operator - https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html)

```
query
|> limit(^page_size)
|> offset(^v_offset) # I don't know if offset var override offset function of Ecto
|> Repo.all
```